# Persistence configuration question

Tags: java, hibernate, jetty, derby, javadb

I have a web application (GWT/Vaadin based), which up to now I launched via

**mvn jetty:run**

Now I want to run it on another web server (also Jetty) and get database connection problems.

In the WAR file there is no persistence.xml file. Can this be the reason for the failure?

If yes, how should I configure the persistence, if

а) I'm using Java DB (Derby),

b) Hibenate and

c) now configure the DB connection like shown below

?

Thanks in advance

Dmitri

```
private void tryToOpenSession(final String aConnectionString)
        throws Throwable {
    ...

    state = PersistenceState.OPENING_CONNECTION;
    final Configuration cnf = new Configuration();
    cnf.setProperty(Environment.DRIVER,
            "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
    cnf.setProperty(Environment.URL, aConnectionString);
    cnf.setProperty(Environment.DIALECT, DerbyDialect.class.getName());
    cnf.setProperty(Environment.SHOW_SQL, "true");
    cnf.setProperty(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "update");
    cnf.setProperty(Environment.CURRENT_SESSION_CONTEXT_CLASS, "thread");

    cnf.addResource("persistence/Entity1.hbm.xml");
    cnf.addResource("persistence/Entity2.hbm.xml");
    ...
    cnf.addResource("persistence/EntityN.hbm.xml");

    sessionFactory = cnf.buildSessionFactory();

    session = getSession();

    ...

    state = PersistenceState.CONNECTION_OPEN;
}
```

UPD: Here's the exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_20]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186) ~[na:1.6.0_20]
    at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:84) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createConnectionProvider(SettingsFactory.java:459) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2833) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2829) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1840) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
```

Comment: I added the stack trace to the question text.

Comment: Did you ever figure out this problem?  I have the same issue.

Comment: Not yet. I got a suggestion to include not only derby.jar file, but also derby-tools.jar. I didn't try it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Exception clearly says that `org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver` or some of its dependencies can't be found in the classpath. Usually you need to put required jar files into `/WEB-INF/lib` (or declare them in `pom.xml` to make Maven put them automatically).

Comment: Well, in the generated WAR file, in pcc.war\WEB-INF\lib\ directory, there is a JAR file derby-10.6.2.1.jar with EmbeddedDriver.class file in org\apache\derby\jdbc\ directory. Why is it not loaded?